# How can I print a String in reverse without local variables one character at a time

Tags: java, string, recursion, char

I have to create a recursive method which will take in a String. it can not store any Strings in this method.

```
public static String printBackwards(String s)
{

    if (s.length() == 0) 
    {
        return s;
    }
    else
    {
        return printBackwards(s.substring(1)) + s.charAt(0);
    }
}
```

This is what i have so far

Example I input a String that says  " Hello " it returns to the terminal o l l e h

Comment: What do you mean by "return the String 1 char at a time"?  What you have seems to work; I don't understand what you need it to do that it isn't doing.

Comment: Could you perhaps give us some example input and expected output? As already mentioned by ajb, I'm not quite sure what you mean by one character at a time.

Comment: You can return a String, or you can return a char, but you can't return a String one char at a time. That doesn't make sense. A method returns one and only one thing, and once.

Comment: @JBNizet Well, you probably *could* return a `String` one char at a time, by defining an `Iterator`.  I kind of doubt that's what the requirement is, though.  Plus, just thinking about writing a recursive iterator is making my head explode.

Comment: Regarding your edit: if all you want to do is put extra spaces between the characters, then you should be able to fix your code by concatenating a space somewhere.

Comment: Regarding your second edit: Earlier, you said "return the String 1 char at a time", but the instructions actually say "print the given String ... one character at a time", which is different.  That's why we couldn't understand you.  I think @manouti's answer is the right one, although you may have to make some tiny changes to get the appearance of the output the way you want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the method itself to print one character at a time. In this case the return type is `void`.

```
public static void printBackwards(String s) {
    if (s.length() != 0) {
        printBackwards(s.substring(1));
        System.out.println(s.charAt(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does SO have an ESP badge for figuring out what a question means even when it's poorly stated?  If so, I nominate you for it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. However, I have built in some... ...slight incorrectnesses into the comments to prevent you from simply copy and pasting it. You better find them before you turn this in – and don't you dare to turn it in without comments ;)

*Note: This does not preserve leading whitespace. You might want to add this as an exercise.*

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class Reverse {

  private static void printBackwards(String line) {

    if (line.length() == 0) {
      /* We are at the end of the line, we can continue */
      out.println();
      return;
    }
    /* We print the _last_ character of the string.
     * Remember, indices start at 0! */
    out.print(line.charAt(line.length() - 1));

    /* We reverse the part of the string we haven't printed */
    printBackwards(line.substring(0, line.length() - 1));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    /* If we don't have anything to input, no action is needed */
    if(args.length > 0) {

      /* Kind of a bonus: Any number of files can be processed */
      for(int a = 0; a<= args.length-1; a++){

        /* We need to construct a Path, since BufferedReader requires one */
        Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(args[a]);

        /* We do not initialize, as we want line to be null if the line.read() fails */
        String line;

        try {

          /* We construct a BufferedReader, which is pretty fast even for large text files */
          BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

          /* Next, we read each line... */
          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
            /* ... and have it reversed */
            printBackwards(line);
          }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          out.print("Something went wrong during line read or during creation of BufferedReader");
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```